# javascript - Get angle value of draggeable arrow D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a problem, I want to get the angle value of the arrow. 
I'm new in D3 and SVG. Here is my code.

Well, I want to move the arrow and get the angle, but i Don't know how. Hope you can help me guys. I'm trying to print something, but I always get undefined or nothing.

```js
var margin = {
 top: 40,
 right: 40,
 bottom: 40,
 left: 40
}

var r = 200;
var hourR = r - 40;

var hourHandLength = 3 * r/3;
var minuteHandLength = r;

var w = d3.select('figure').node().clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var h = d3.select('figure').node().clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
 .on('dragstart', dragstart)
 .on('drag', drag)
 .on('dragend', dragend);

var handData = [
 {
  type:'hour',
  value:0,
  length:-hourHandLength,
 }
];

var svg = d3.select('svg')
 .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append('g')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

var face = g.append('g')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + r + ',' + r + ')');

face.append('circle')
 .attr({
  class: 'outline',
  r: r,
  cx: 0,
  cy: 0,
  fill: '#a0a0a0'
 });
  
var hands = face.append('g');

hands.selectAll('line')
 .data(handData)
.enter().append('line')
 .attr({
  class: function(d) { return d.type + '-hand'; },
  x1: 0,
  y1: 0,
  x2: function(d) {
    
   return d.length * Math.cos(d.value);
  },
  y2: function(d) {
   return d.length * Math.sin(d.value);
  }
 })
 .call(drag);

face.append('circle')
 .attr({
  cx: 0,
  cy: 0,
  r: 15,
  fill: 'black',
  'stroke': '#374140',
  'stroke-width': 5
 });

function dragstart() {
}

function drag() {
 
 var rad = Math.atan2(d3.event.y, d3.event.x);
 
 d3.select(this)
  .attr({
   x2: function(d) {
    return r * Math.cos(rad);
   },
   y2: function(d) {
    return r * Math.sin(rad);
   }
  });
}

function dragend() {
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Mono);

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background-color: #374140;
 font-family: 'Nova Mono';
}

figure {
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
}

.outline {
 stroke: white;
 stroke-width: 1;
}

.hour {
 stroke: white;
 stroke-width: 4;
}

.hour-hand {
 stroke: white;
 stroke-width: 12;
 stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<figure>
 <svg></svg>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can calculate the angle based on the x,y coordinates of both ends of the line. I have added an `id` to your svg line to access it later in your `drag` function.

In your drag function, I first access the different position values and then calculate the theta value and then convert to degrees like the following:

```
  var angle = Math.atan2(y2Pos - y1Pos, x2Pos - x1Pos) * 180 / Math.PI + 180;
```

Check working snippet below:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 40,
  right: 40,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 40
}

var r = 200;
var hourR = r - 40;

var hourHandLength = 3 * r / 3;
var minuteHandLength = r;

var w = d3.select('figure').node().clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var h = d3.select('figure').node().clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on('dragstart', dragstart)
  .on('drag', drag)
  .on('dragend', dragend);

var handData = [{
  type: 'hour',
  value: 0,
  length: -hourHandLength,
}];

var svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

var face = g.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + r + ',' + r + ')');

face.append('circle')
  .attr({
    class: 'outline',
    r: r,
    cx: 0,
    cy: 0,
    fill: '#a0a0a0'
  });

var hands = face.append('g');

hands.selectAll('line')
  .data(handData)
  .enter().append('line')
  .attr("id", "hand")
  .attr({
    class: function(d) {
      return d.type + '-hand';
    },
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: function(d) {

      return d.length * Math.cos(d.value);
    },
    y2: function(d) {
      return d.length * Math.sin(d.value);
    }
  })
  .call(drag);



face.append('circle')
  .attr({
    cx: 0,
    cy: 0,
    r: 15,
    fill: 'black',
    'stroke': '#374140',
    'stroke-width': 5
  });

function dragstart() {}

function drag() {

  var rad = Math.atan2(d3.event.y, d3.event.x);

  d3.select(this)
    .attr({
      x2: function(d) {
        return r * Math.cos(rad);
      },
      y2: function(d) {
        return r * Math.sin(rad);
      }
    });

  var singleLine = hands.selectAll('#hand');
  var x1Pos = singleLine.attr("x1");
  var x2Pos = singleLine.attr("x2");
  var y1Pos = singleLine.attr("y1");
  var y2Pos = singleLine.attr("y2");

  var angle = Math.atan2(y2Pos - y1Pos, x2Pos - x1Pos) * 180 / Math.PI + 180;
  console.log(angle);
}

function dragend() {}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Mono);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #374140;
  font-family: 'Nova Mono';
}

figure {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

.outline {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.hour {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 4;
}

.hour-hand {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 12;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<figure>
  <svg></svg>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It solve my problem. Thank you, really.

Comment: Hello, would you know the answer to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696831/d3-force-directed-graph-why-dont-the-flags-appear